# Время жизни объекта в Redis

Tags: php, yii2, redis

Как правильно задать время жизни объекту в redis? 
Для записи данных использую класс yii\redis\ActiveRecord

Конфиг:

```
'redis' => [
    'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Время жизни задается при создании ключа третьим параметром функций `addValue()` или `setValue()`

```
$redis->setValue('key', 'value', 3600);
```